# jQuery Accordion doesn't load unless I refresh the page

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, accordion

I am trying to use Accordion in my page, but it doesn't load unless I refresh the page.

Here is the link:  http://mzprojects.net/191stband/191stband.html

click on the menu panel and click ensembles.  The accordion does not work unless you refresh you page.  Please look at the source code for the ensembles html page.

Can anybody please help with this?  I am kinda stuck on this.  Greatly appreciate your help!!

*New observation: If I type in the url: http://mzprojects.net/191stband/ensembles.html, It works.  But when I try to go to this page from my navigation panel, it won't load the jQuery UI unless I refresh...

Comment: jQM loads pages via ajax and only loads the the first div with data-role="page". Therefore your script that initializes the accordion is not loaded and run.  Move the script inside the data-role=page DIV or load the page without ajax: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

Comment: I moved the Javascript under the data-role="page" div.  It kidna solve the problem that the accordion lay out is there, but all the contents are showing unless I refresh it.  Thanks

Comment: You are also mixing jQueryUI and jQuery Mobile. Is there any reason you don't use the collapsibleset widget to make a jQM accordion: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsibleset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling

$( ".selector" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );

after it's created and before the page is shown.

"Collapsibleset" is JQM's name for accordion.